# Other files than php files not being processed; php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I run a website under a a virtualhost 
The apache server runs with php7 and php-fpm. I'm running all this on CentOS 7.
Whenever I try to access the website it processes the PHP files but not the css files or any other file like jpg.

```
<VirtualHost www.example.com:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/htdocs"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log combined


<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    #ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/example.com/htdocs/$1
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/example.com/htdocs/$1

</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/example.com/htdocs">
    #Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

The logs reports 403 for css files and other resources other than php.

```
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [04/Dec/2016:14:07:45 +0100] "GET /admin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5957 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [04/Dec/2016:14:07:45 +0100] "GET /admin/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 403 15 "http..../admin/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [04/Dec/2016:14:07:45 +0100] "GET /admin/css/demo.css HTTP/1.1" 403 15 "http..../admin/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [04/Dec/2016:14:07:45 +0100] "GET /admin/css/animate-custom.css HTTP/1.1" 403 15 "http..../admin/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36"
```

I am lost to what I have done incorrect.
I am open to any suggestion.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: HTTP 403 means you're accessing a forbidden resource that you're not allowed to access.

Comment: This usually happens when you have `.htaccess` set to restrict these resources from accessing or there is an another case in which you don't have enough file permissions set to read or write or execute these resources. Linux always requires these files to have permissions set.

Comment: Open up Terminal. Change your directory to the one where these resources exist using `cd` command. Then, execute `chmod -R 755 .`. This should help you.

Comment: chmod 755 recursively did not work and I have no htaccess file.

My guess is that ProxyPassMatch is not matching those files that get 403.
But I fail to see the regex error.

 ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/example.com/htdocs/$1

PS: The commented line gave the same results.

Comment: You added the proxymatch lines yourself?

Comment: Yes, I created the vhost myself by example on the net.

Comment: You did `chmod -R 755 .` on the project root folder? or you could do it to the whole `www` directory like `chmod -R 755 /var/www/`.

Comment: I have stumbled upon 'security.limit_extensions'

I got the message: "has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" for the files that where denied, I fixed this, but the resources are still not loading despite they are getting a HTTP 200 on their requests. Maybe still a ProxyPassMatch issue?

Comment: Maybe. Try removing all those `ProxyPassMatch` lines and check it out if it works.

Comment: How did you come to this suggestion? After removing the ProxyPassMatch the pages were all dressed with css, etc.

Comment: Dressed with CSS. Lol. So, you mean it worked?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, great suggestion, so you think that the restriction was due to the ProxyPassMatch?

I need to do some more investigation about ProxyPassMatch and why I should use it for mpm_event (or not)

Comment: Maybe because of that. But if those lines were already existed, you should not remove them or if you added them yourself, leave them removed unless they don't a make big impact.